# IEnumerable, requires two implementations?

Tags: c#, interface

I am learning about implementing interfaces and generics, I made this code, but VStudio says that I did not implement System.Collections.Enumerable.GetEnumerator().
Did I not do this below, generically? It wants two implementations?

```
namespace Generic_cars
{
 class VehicleLot:IEnumerable<Vehicle>
 {
    public List<Vehicle> Lot = new List<Vehicle>();

    IEnumerator<Vehicle> IEnumerable<Vehicle>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (Vehicle v in Lot) { yield return v; };
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are implementing `IEnumerable<Vehicle>`, a generic interface that is strongly typed to hold `Vehicle` objects. That interface, however, derives from the older `IEnumerable` interace that is not generic, and is typed to hold `object` objects.

If you want to implement the generic version (which you do) you need to also implement the non-generic version. Typically you would implement the non-generic `GetEnumerator` by simply calling the generic version.

Also, you probably *don't* want to be explicitly implementing `GetEnumerator<Vehicle>` the way you are; that will require you to explicitly cast your objects to `IEnumerable<Vehicle>` in order to use them. Instead, you probably want to do this:

```
public IEnumerator<Vehicle> GetEnumerator() {
    foreach( Vehicle item in items ) {
        yield return item;
    }
}

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
    return GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: I think it's worth noting that `IEnumerable` should be explicitely implemented while `IEnumerable<T>` should be implicitely.

Comment: @Guillaume yeah I just noticed his explicit implementation in the question and updated my answer.

Comment: Wow, explicit vs implicit is confusing when it comes to Interfaces. I get it though, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do this way and your life will be all good.

```
class VehicleLot : List<Vehicle>
{

}
```

Now *VehicleLot* is your collection class. You can do any operation as you do on any other collection.

Usage:

```
VehicleLot list = new VehicleLot();
list.Add(new Vehicle()); // you can add as many Vehicles as you want
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's better when your class doesn't implement IEnumerable itself. You can just create a property and return your list as IEnumerable:

```
namespace Generic_cars
{
 class VehicleLot
 {
    public List<Vehicle> Lot = new List<Vehicle>();

    IEnumerable<Vehicle> Vehicles
    {
        return Lot;
    }
 }
}
```